# Placing a counter incrementing and decrementing when items are added and removed using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Please find the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var c=1;
        $("#i1").toggle(function(){
            $("#e1").appendTo("#i2");
            $('#counter').attr('value',c);

        },
        function(){
            $("#e1").appendTo($(this));
           $('#counter').attr('value',c);
        });
    c++; 
    });
    </script>
    <div id=i1><span id="e1">Item 1</span></div>
    <div id=i2><span id="e2">Item 2</span></div>

    <input type=text value='' id=counter>
```

When the counter is placed, it does increment and decrement, but the value goes up by +2 each time I click on add, and -1 on remove.

What exactly is wrong

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 0):

I don't realy understand your code.
Are there parts missing?

But I think it's because, the *c++* will be called only once, when the document.ready runs.
and *1+1 = 2*, so *c* will always be *2*.

So maybe thats why it always increment with 2.

But I think when

```
 $('#counter').attr('value',c);
```

is called, it will always be 2... and not added with 2.

If i use a counter for appending items, is use a hidden field, and would do something like this:

```
$("#i1").toggle(function(){
    var c= $("#counter").val();
    c++;
    $("#counter").val(c);
    $("#e1").appendTo("#i2");
    $('#counter').attr('value',c);
},
function(){
    var c= $("#counter").val();
    c++;
    $("#counter").val(c);
    $("#e1").appendTo($(this));
    $('#counter').attr('value',c);
});
```

I hope this was useful.

Comment: At the second function it must decrement

Comment: did that with the same result
I just cannot find out why it is being incremented